# SQL Server Linked server to Oracle

Tags: sql, linked-server

I have a SQL server instance that has a Linked server to an Oracle instance on another box.  We are receiving the below error.

```
    Msg 7302, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
    Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "MY_ORACLE".
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They recycled the server last week and that fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you haven't installed the OLE DB provider for Oracle. It has to be installed on the SQL Server machine.  It's made by Microsoft and only available in a 32-bit version.

You're probably better off installing Oracle's own OLE DB drivers for windows.  They're called the "Oracle Data Access Components for Windows" and you can find them [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/downloads/index.html).

Comment: @Andomar...I'll have the DBA take a look.  That seems to make sense

Comment: @Andomar...looks like a server issue. They recycled the server last week and that fixed it. But, we made pathces this week. But it looks like a 32 vs 64 bit issue. Thanks